# Android Studio - Add to ArrayList and Draw

Tags: java, android, arraylist, ondraw

I am trying to draw onto a musical score, however i cant seem to add Notes dynamically after runtime i.e. on the click of a button.

I am trying to Draw an ArrayList, of which the ArrayList is updated by a separate method.

However, i have tried to use postInvalidate() and Invalidate() within the onDraw method and the newNote() method as below.

The list does not want to be redrawn.

Can anyone please enlighten me as to how do draw onto the Canvas.

**Music.java**

```
ArrayList<Note> notes = new ArrayList<Note>();

public void newNote(){
    notes.add(new Note(getContext(), null, distanceBetweenLines * 2, 2,x + (lastXValue += distanceBetweenNotes),y + 8 * distanceBetweenLines));
    Log.e(TAG,String.valueOf(notes.size()));
    postInvalidate();
    //invalidate();
}

@Override
protected void onDraw(Canvas g) {
    super.onDraw(g);
    for (int i = 0; i < notes.size(); i++) {
        Note not = (Note) notes.get(i);
        not.draw(g);
    }
    invalidate();
}
```

**MainActivity.java**

```
    btnPlay.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            music.newNote();
            music.invalidate();
        }
    });
```

**Note.java**

```
import android.content.Context;
import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.graphics.BitmapFactory;
import android.graphics.Canvas;
import android.graphics.Color;
import android.graphics.Paint;
import android.util.AttributeSet;

public class Note {

    private int x, y;
    private int dur;
    private int distance;
    private int mast;
    Paint paint;
    Context context;

    public Note(Context con, AttributeSet set, int d, int dur,int x,int y) {
        context = con;
        this.dur = dur;
        distance = 2*d;
        paint = new Paint();
        paint.setStrokeWidth(6);
        this.x = x;
        this.y = y;
    }
    /*
    public void setNW(int x, int y) {
        this.x = x;
        this.y = y;
    }
*/
    private void drawMinim(Canvas g) {
        Bitmap bm = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(context.getResources(), R.mipmap.minim);
        g.drawBitmap(bm,x,y,new Paint());
        bm.recycle();
    }

    private void drawCrotchet(Canvas g) {
        Bitmap bm = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(context.getResources(), R.mipmap.crotchet);
        int widthOffset = bm.getWidth()/2;
        int heightOffset = bm.getHeight()/10;
        g.drawBitmap(bm,x,y,new Paint());
        bm.recycle();
    }

    private void drawQuaver(Canvas g) {
        Bitmap bm = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(context.getResources(), R.mipmap.quaver);
        g.drawBitmap(bm,x,y,new Paint());
        bm.recycle();
    }

    private void drawDottedCrotchet(Canvas g) {
        Bitmap bm = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(context.getResources(), R.mipmap.crotchet_dot);
        g.drawBitmap(bm,x,y,new Paint());
        bm.recycle();
    }
    private void drawDottedMinim(Canvas g) {
        Bitmap bm = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(context.getResources(), R.mipmap.minim_dot);
        g.drawBitmap(bm,x,y,new Paint());
        bm.recycle();
    }

    private void drawSemiBreve(Canvas g) {
        Bitmap bm = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(context.getResources(), R.mipmap.semibreve);
        Bitmap b = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(bm, 75, 75, false);
        g.drawBitmap(b,x,y,new Paint());
        b.recycle();
    }

    public void draw(Canvas g) {
        switch (dur) {
            case 0:
                break;
            case 1:  drawQuaver(g);
                break;
            case 2:  drawCrotchet(g);
                break;
            case 3:  drawDottedCrotchet(g);
                break;
            case 4:  drawMinim(g);
                break;
            case 6:  drawDottedMinim(g);
                break;
            case 8:  drawSemiBreve(g);
                break;
            default:
                break;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: What class is `Music.java` extending? If its some layout, make sure to call `setWillNotDraw(false)`, otherwise your `onDraw(...)` function will not be called at all.

Comment: The Music Class extends view.

Comment: Found the issue! - i was using a CustomView in the XML file. This had issues the manual instantiation, so put simply i had two Entities of the Music Class. The XML CustomView creates its own Constructor which i wasnt using. This guide helped ----- http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33300451/ondraw-method-work-only-when-i-creating-my-object-in-the-ondraw